# Three.js - there is no texture bound to the unit 0 Error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, opengl-es, three.js, webgl

Since today's Chrome update (Version 50.0.2661.86 (64-bit) OSX), my three.js based application started outputting this warning :

**`[.CommandBufferContext]RENDER WARNING: there is no texture bound to the unit 0`**

and the application is not loading anymore (it's just stuck in the loading screen).

To give a context of the strangeness of this error, we are instancing meshes with a texture + normal map, and there is a weird behaviour where : 
- if we load all the instances the application crashes
- if we load fewer instances, the applications loads

For info, we load all the textures in the material creation callback, so the previous Stackoverflow answers giving solutions about this issue don't really work.

Does anyone have any idea of what we could change to make this work ? Or should we open a ticket to the Chromium team reporting an issue ?

It was working perfectly before today's update.

Comment: This may be a dumb suggestion, sorry, just thinking of low hanging fruit first.... Have you the latest Three? Three is at v76.

Comment: revision 76 is the one we're using, indeed.

Comment: I found this thread https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/8666 perhaps it is of some use. I think without a Fiddle which reproduces the code, the thread is the most promising source of info.

Comment: so according to the thread it's a bug in chrome and a fix is comming

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=604844

Comment: there also seemed to be some temporary work arounds in the thread.

Comment: thanks a lot. by using the temporary workaround by 'aramavetisyan' on the thread, my application is saved!

Comment: I had the same problem - though i'm not using Three.js, i'm posting my two cents here because this is the only question on SO about this problem, and is *not* Three.js related.
By setting unused samplers to null, the warnings are gone. Example: `gl.uniform1i(program.uniforms['s_texture'], null);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add:

```
this.image = image; // retain a reference to the object to prevent garbage collection
```

after line 18419 of three.js (r76), it will also correct the TextureLoader hang in the newest version of Chrome.

Comment: I don't think this is a good answer. You are not providing any context, which makes it impossible to solve the problem for anyone beyond those having three.js (r76).

Comment: Who cares at this point?  It's been fixed for months.  What I posted was a temporary fix.

Comment: I care because I got here due to a similar error message occuring in another product (openjscad.org).  It would be valuable to understand the cause for this, which component is at fault, and how to troubleshoot it when it happens again.

Comment: Similar error message..  another product..  I don't see how it's relevant to this thread.